# Why is it undefined behavior to call `std::subrange` in a `std::string` `std::functional` lambda stored in a `std::vector`?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++20, c++-concepts, std-ranges

Consider the following code, which contains a templated `std::vector` type of `std::function` objects which consume a `const & std::range` and `std::range::iterator`. What causes the `position` `std::ranges::iterator_t` passed into the `std::functional` lambda to be invalidated, such that on `g++` and `clang++`, the `std::cout` iteration goes passed the end of the `std::string`?

```cpp
#include <ranges>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

int main(const int, const char * []) {
    auto consume = [](const auto & source, auto position) {
        auto consumption = std::ranges::subrange(position, std::end(source));
        for (auto res : consumption) {
            std::cout << res;
        }
    };

    std::vector<std::function<void(
            std::string,
            std::string::const_iterator)>> lambdas{consume};
    const auto range = std::string("hello");
    lambdas.back()(range, std::begin(range));
}
```

I am uncertain what else is unnecessary for the [minimal viable example](https://godbolt.org/z/3rW6PGM9Y) [(Better ASAN'd version courtesy of @Marek R)](https://godbolt.org/z/fM7q4brbx), but I've done my best to trim.

Comment: [better godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/fM7q4brbx)

Comment: `range` is passed by value to the `std::function`, and `std::begin(range)` is not a valid iterator of the copy.

Comment: @molbdnilo I see. How would you forward the iterator in a valid way to `std::function`? Do I need to explicitly call `std::move`?

Comment: You wouldn't; you would avoid copying `range` by using an appropriate `std::function` instantiation.

Comment: Ah, I was missing a `&`. Thanks.